# How to setup java development environment i.e. jdk and eclipse IDE on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am new to MAC and need the same development environment as I was using on my Windows 7. There I was using JDK 6 and Eclipse.
Now I want to know how do I setup the same environment on this Mac machine.

Comment: Unzip Eclipse into a directory and run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macs come with a JDK already installed so you should be good there. For eclipse you just need to download and install it. Same as Windows. Choose the 64 bit Eclipse and you should be good.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: I have downloaded the **eclipse.tar.gz** file from the eclipse downloads and also I have downloaded **javadeveloper.osx.jdk.dmg** Please help me further with these downloaded files. How to progress further as I have stated that I am new to MAC OS X.

Comment: You shouldn't need to download a JDK. Open up a terminal window and type java -version and see what you get.

Comment: I googled and did the same but in OS X 10.7 there is no default jre installed. Then I clicked on the java preferences an then a software update was done by which jre 6 was installed. But for the development purpose jre is not enough that is why I am downloading jdk.

Comment: Didn't realize one wasn't included with 10.7 now. Must be a change now that Oracle has taken over Java releases for OS X.

Comment: By the way what do I do with .dmg file that I have downloaded. What is it and how is it installed. Is it like an .exe on windows?

Comment: Check out this article. Basically a dmg is an image file like an ISO. You'll double click to open it and then drag the application to your applications folder. First time using a Mac? http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/779/

Comment: @pKs: a `dmg` is a disk image - double click it and it will open the disk image - inside is probably an installer to run, or a application to copy into `Applications` ...

Comment: @jjathman You got me right I am very new thanks for the help in installation of _.dmg,_ now I want one more help with the _eclipse.tar.gz_ file that I have to extract to run. How to do this now.

Comment: If you double click on it then it will automatically uncompress in the same folder. You should then be able to open the folder and see an icon that looks like an application. Possibly in the bin folder. Better yet I think eclipse has a dmg installer for OS X. Did you see that?

Comment: @GregKopff Thanks for info. Can you help in the extraction of tar.gz file.

Comment: No I didn't see anything like that, you meant to say eclipse.dmg inspire of eclipse.tar.gz . No I didn't find this. Would it be a problem if I use jdk.dmg and with that eclipse.tar.gz file?

Comment: Yeah I don't see a dmg for eclipse either. The tar.gz file will work just fine.